# Was honey used preserve psychoactive mushrooms in the ancient past?

Tags: anthropology, honey

[I have read](http://www.shroomery.org/9945/The-Tale-of-blue-honey) personal reports of adding mushrooms to honey to effect preservation.

> To save the magic, all one needs to do is immerse those morsels in raw honey and stash them in a cool, shady place, and let osmosis do its thing. The honey will first turn amber, then a deep blue-black color indicating that the honey has become psychoactive. At this point it is time to strain out the mushrooms from the honey.

It also asserts that this is an ancient practice.

> The answer comes to us born on the w7inds (sic) of time. Kosmic, karmic trade winds from an ancient Mayan past.

I have never seen evidence that I would consider 'anthropological' or 'archeological', to document the ancient use of honey to preserve mushrooms.

Can anyone provide sources?

Comment: [Odyssey, book 10](http://classics.mit.edu/Homer/odyssey.10.x.html): "When she [Circe] had got them into her house, she set them upon benches and seats and mixed them a mess with cheese, honey, meal, and Pramnian but she drugged it with wicked poisons to make them forget their homes, and when they had drunk she turned them into pigs by a stroke of her wand, and shut them up in her pigsties. They were like pigs-head, hair, and all, and they grunted just as pigs do; but their senses were the same as before, and they remembered everything." Sounds a lot like shrooms, doesn't it? ;P

Comment: Related (on History.SE): [What are the archaeological evidence for the Aztec's use of entheogens?](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/5524/what-are-the-archaeological-evidence-for-the-aztecs-use-of-entheogens)